# Passing a local value to a React class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I hope I was able to phrase this so as to make any sense. In any case, I'm a complete noob and can't figure out how to avoid hardcoding the optional class name inside this React button:

```
<button value='dogs' className={imageOptions === 'dogs' ? "options-button option-active" : "options-button"} onClick={(e) =\> handleImageOptions(e)}\>
   Dogs
</button\>
```

I was thinking it would be as simple as

```
className={imageOptions === value ? "options-button option-active"
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

```
 <button
            value="dogs"
            className={`${
              imageOptions === "dogs"
                ? "options-button option-active"
                : "options-button"
            }`}
            onClick={(e) => handleImageOptions(e)}
          >
            Dogs
          </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
className={`options-button ${(imageOptions === 'dogs') && 'option-active'}}
```

Comment: So there's no way not to hardcode it? Thanks for your answers, I have tried to upvote but I don't have enough reputation :))

Comment: How would it tell if it's optional if you don't _include_ the option?